# d3.js text transition if string is too long

Tags: javascript, d3.js

i have a div with a fixed width but sometimes the text inside it can overflow. I would like to create an animation during the mouseover in which the text starts "flowing" inside the div.

An example could be:
the string is *"this is a simple test"*
but the div can contains only *"this is a"*.
so when overing on it, the text become:

"his is a "--->"is is a s" ---> "s is a si"--> " is a sim".... and so on

Comment: Do you need to use `d3`? It might not be the best solution if you aren't working with svg.

Comment: what else could i use?

Comment: Added a d3 alternative answer.

Answer (score 0):

How about a marquee?

```html
<marquee width="50px" direction="right" height="100px">
this is a simple test
</marquee>
```